# Mock module in code run by selenium's webdriver

Tags: python, django, selenium, mocking

My code is running some instances of threading.Thread for some long asynchronous tasks.

This does not allow me running my django unittests using sqlite backend, because sqlite can not handle multiple connections in threads. Thus, I am successfully mocking Thread with a FakeThread class that i wrote (it simply runs the target synchronously).

However, the mock does not seem to work for selenium tests. I do:

```py
from tests.stubs import FakeThread

# ...
class FunctionalTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    @mock.patch('accounts.models.user_profile.Thread', new=FakeThread)
    def test_register_agency(self):
        self.browser.get("%s%s" % (self.live_server_url, "/register"))
        # .. fill in form, submit, eventually calls something in user_profile
        # using an instance of Thread. Thread seems to still be threading.Thread
```

Any idea how to mock Thread in the code that selenium runs when serving my browser calls? Thank  you!

Comment: Can you use a singleton pattern or do you need to access the database multiple times?

Have you tried utilizing serialization to prevent true duplicate access at the same time?

If those don't work you can always do a lock while accessing the database in your data layer.  Then all access will have to wait to get the lock before they can utilize the connection.

Comment: Hi @mutt, thanks for your help! I am using django framework and delegate database connection management in there. That would be diff to rewire. Sqlite states "Pysqlite’s default behavior is to prohibit the usage of a single connection in more than one thread. This is originally intended to work with older versions of SQLite that did not support multithreaded operation under various circumstances. In particular, older SQLite versions did not allow a:memory: database to be used in multiple threads under any circumstances."

Comment: I think I am gonna use a factory for Thread, although i'm not very happy changing app code for testing. I forgot to add i use in-memory Sqlite because it is blazing fast for test runs.

Comment: That makes sense...although I think you could still try the serialization of the communication to prevent overlap.  That might work with minimal changes...